# Laying Out Login Screen In Xcode - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, constraints

I have a login layout and I want it to work universally on 4 inch, 4.7 and 5.5 inch screens.

I want everything to be as if the screen was "one" and I just made it all x% larger or bigger to stretch and fit the screen.

Comment: What constraints are you using? Please share what you have done so far.

Comment: You should be using proportional constraints, which do exactly what you are asking. I've also submitted an edit to remove the unnecessary commentary as the problem here is a lack of experience with the platform rather than the platform itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the challenge in doing this is that different components are adjusted in different ways to scale with screen size, as well as that there are a few ways to do some of those.

Lets look at a few:

- You can use Autoresizing to scale a view automatically with with the size of it's superview/container (so this applies to changing from portrait to landscape). You can find this in the size inspector (if you haven't set constraints). You can see an in depth [tutorial on it here](https://youtu.be/pI-yolo9NrM).
  [image]

This let's you set both spacing and internal space based on where you place the view originally.

- Another way is setting constraints in relationship to another view with a ratio other than 1:1. For example, you can set a constraint of your button to the superview as equal widths and edit that constraint's ratio/multiplier to 1:2 to make it 50% the size or 1:4 to make it 25% of the width, etc'.

[image]

- For the fonts you should probably use Autoshrink. You can see a [detailed answer about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35154493/8083912).