# How to make UILabel and UITextField font size to be relative to screen size

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextfield, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view controller which has a text field and label and I have set height constraint for text field and label and so I feel font size is not relative to the screen I believe.

How can I make this items' font size to be relative to the screen size?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153363/how-to-dynamically-change-the-font-size-in-auto-layout-ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change the font size in auto layout iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153363/how-to-dynamically-change-the-font-size-in-auto-layout-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually change `UIlabel` or `UITextfield` font in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your `ViewController` or `layoutSubviews` method of your `superView`. Like this:

```
CGRect screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFont-Name"  
    size:screenSize.size.width/15.f];
```